# Drupal 8 - Absolute url in content

Tags: sql, database, drupal, migration, drupal-8

I'm migrating my website from dev environment to production environment so the absolute path url entered in CkEditor, Content or fields by users won't work on the domain.

What can I do?
Database can be huge so I'm looking for something else than search and replace in a 40 mo sql file.

I'm on Drupal 8 with mysql

Comment: best way to resolve that problem is to build a sql script of your own to target each field you want. Quite simple and not that long.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply find which tables/fields in db contain your absolute urls you want to replace. And then replace it in mysql. Here is an example:

```
$fields_to_update = [
    ['table' => 'field_data_body', 'field' => 'body_value'],
    ['table' => 'field_data_body', 'field' => 'body_summary'],
    ['table' => 'field_data_field_account_notes', 'field' => 'field_account_notes_value'],
    ['table' => 'field_data_field_extra_text', 'field' => 'field_extra_text_value'],
  ];

  foreach ($fields_to_update as $item) {

    $table = $item['table'];
    $field = $item['field'];

    db_query("UPDATE {$table} SET $field = REPLACE($field, 'http://www.example.com/', :new_name) WHERE $field LIKE BINARY '%http://www.example.com/%'", array(':new_name' => '/'));

  }
```

hope it helps